# Preventing iframe injection via url?

Tags: php, security, url, iframe, code-injection

I'm trying to prevent attacks where a url can be distributed that inserts an iframe (containing a fake login screen) into a PHP site using javascript in the url. Is there some way with PHP to clean out URLs of a page before it is loaded?

The url looks like something like: `login.php?login_nav_map=%2Fv3%2Farchives%2Findex.php%22/%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22no.jpg%22%20onerror=%22document.write%28String.fromCharCode%2860,99,101,110,116,101,114,62,10,60,105,109,103,32,115,114,99,61,34,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,119,119,119,46,119,111,114,108,100,116,118,112,99,46,99,111,109,47,98,108,111,45,99,111,110,116,101,110,116,47,117,112,108,111,97,100,115,47,50,48,49,49,47,48,56,47,97,98,99,45,111,110,108,105,110,101,45,116,118,46,106,112,103,34,47,62,60,98,114,47,62,10,60,104,49,62,65,100,`

and the char codes insert an iframe into my page which I do not want there.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really confusing so I'll try to answer a few questions and hopefully it helps.

**You have a web page that you don't want people loading in an iframe.**

Use a frame breakout script, usually something like

```
if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href ;
}
```

**You have a web page where people can post stuff and you don't want somebody typing in an iframe code and it loading a frame on your page.**

Sanitize the input. Take a look at [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). That'll convert `<` and `>` (among others) to their HTML entities so everything will be visible on the page but the browser won't parse any tags as code. No more `<script>`, it'll show up as just  instead of executing the code inside.

**You have a website where the URL parameters mean something in the code and you don't want somebody putting a malicious URL as a parameter.** Something like `http://mysite.com?foo=bar&url=somebadwebsite.com/virus.php`

You should have a blacklist of URLs or domains to block. Look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the parts of the URL and you can have use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if the `host` is part of the blacklisted array.

**You have a website where the URL parameters control the content of the page.** Something like `http://mysite.com?foo=bar&title=Hello` and it displays "Hello" on the page. You wouldn't want somebody injecting JS there and your page to execute that.

It's usually a bad idea to do this. You should have a whitelist of possible values in this case.

```
$value = $_GET['title']
switch ($value) {
    case 'Hello':
        // do something for hello
        break;
    case 'Goodbye':
        // do something for goodbye
        break;
    default:
        // do something if it's something you don't expect/want as input
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use htmlentities on the actual url. I'll edit my question to clarify a bit

Comment: i've added an example of the type of URL I'm trying to block. no parameter based content. a blacklist of sites seems unmaintainable, I was thinking of a way to strip htmltags and js from the url of any page that gets loaded

Comment: Is there a common solution to preventing this sort of thing. is it possible to do this sort of spoofing on most sites? I'm surprised I'm not finding more resources about this specific type of attack.

Comment: The solution is to NOT use the value in the parameter in the URL directly, as I described in my answer. Why are you writing whatever in the URL on the page? And even then, does the JS only affect me (the person who did it) or every other person who visits after me, too?